# Making a DIV hide if viewport drops below set width

Tags: jquery, html, hide, viewport

I've been working/searching for this specific idea for a while, but I can't seem to find a solution.

Basically I'm working with a wordpress plugin, where a piece of content is shown, and it works fine except for mobile devices.

I'm trying to fix this by making the DIV hide when the viewport hits a certain width.

This is what I have so far:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
var screen = $(window)    
if (screen.width() < 800) {
    $("#attentionGrabber").hide();
}
else {
    $("#attentionGrabber").show();
}
});</script>
```

This is assuming #attentionGrabber is the div I'm trying to control.

I think that is the most simple way to show or hide it depending on the viewport, but nothing seems to happen when I place that code in the header.

Comment: Any reason you're not using media queries (CSS3)?

Comment: yes... I know that's what I should be doing. But I have absolutely no clue how to do those or implement them... I know CSS when it comes to styling like colors/borders/width/etc. but I don't know what media queries are.

Comment: Time to learn. :-) See my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to bind to some event so that your function runs when the screen is resized.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).resize(function () {
    var screen = $(window)    
    if (screen.width() < 800) {
        $("#attentionGrabber").hide();
    }
    else {
        $("#attentionGrabber").show();
    }
});
</script>
```

Really, though, I'd go this route:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 799px) {
    #attentionGrabber {display: none}
}
```

http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

Comment: Thanks, i'll read up on it. I'm assuming the media query works the same way as basic CSS, as in I can just throw it into my CSS file and it'll work?

Comment: Yes indeed. Check out the linked article or any of the many like it.

Comment: Please be aware that media queries do not work with IE 9 and below. They are amazing, but are not supported by the sad old browser.

Comment: I'm doing it mainly for mobile devices, so its no big deal. Also, I just put it into my site, works awesome! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you imported  jquery m befor your script

```
 <script
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"
type="text/javascript"  >
```

Then

```
      <script type="text/javascript"  >
$(document).ready(function() {

function _resizeTDiv()
{
  ..your code here
}
 _resizeTDiv();

$(window).resize(function() {
 _resizeTDiv();
});

});

</script>
```